# Feeding Classifier data from LSTM Autoencoder

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, autoencoder

## Goal:

I have built a LSTM autoencoder for the purpose of feature reduction. My plan is to encode some input and feed it to a classifier in the future. The encoder takes data of the shape `[batch_size, timesteps, features_of_timesteps` However in the output layer of the encoder portion I am returning just the last hidden state in the form `[1, timesteps, features_of_timesteps]`.

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, first_layer, second_layer, n_layers):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.encode = nn.Sequential(nn.LSTM(input_size, first_layer, batch_first=True),
                                    getSequence(),
                                    nn.ReLU(True),
                                    nn.LSTM(first_layer, second_layer),
                                    getLast())
        self.decode = nn.Sequential(nn.LSTM(second_layer, first_layer, batch_first=True),
                                    getSequence(),
                                    nn.ReLU(True),
                                    nn.LSTM(first_layer, input_size),
                                    getSequence())

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.float()
        x = self.encode(x)
        x = x.repeat(batch_size, 1, 1)
        x = self.decode(x)
        return x
```

## Worry:

I am afraid that the last hidden state of the my second LSTM layer in the encoding portion of the model is summarizing the entire batch along with decreasing the feature dimensionality. This feels wrong because I am trying to reduce a single timeseries into a smaller vector, not an entire batch of timeseries into one vector. Am I correct in my worries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have multiple problem in your code, for simplicity, I just give you one well defined model instead, following code build a **LSTM Autoencoder** that reconstruct the inputs with shape `(batch_size, timesteps, number_of_features_at_each_timesteps)`:

```
import torch
from torch import nn

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

class Encoder(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, seq_len, n_features, embedding_dim=64):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()

    self.seq_len, self.n_features = seq_len, n_features
    self.embedding_dim, self.hidden_dim = embedding_dim, 2 * embedding_dim

    self.rnn1 = nn.LSTM(
      input_size=n_features,
      hidden_size=self.hidden_dim,
      num_layers=1,
      batch_first=True
    )
    self.rnn2 = nn.LSTM(
      input_size=self.hidden_dim,
      hidden_size=self.embedding_dim,
      num_layers=1,
      batch_first=True
    )

  def forward(self, x):
    x, (_, _) = self.rnn1(x)
    x, (hidden_n, _) = self.rnn2(x)
    return hidden_n

class Decoder(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, seq_len, input_dim=64, n_features=1):
    super(Decoder, self).__init__()

    self.seq_len, self.input_dim = seq_len, input_dim
    self.hidden_dim, self.n_features = 2 * input_dim, n_features

    self.rnn1 = nn.LSTM(
      input_size=input_dim,
      hidden_size=input_dim,
      num_layers=1,
      batch_first=True
    )
    self.rnn2 = nn.LSTM(
      input_size=input_dim,
      hidden_size=self.hidden_dim,
      num_layers=1,
      batch_first=True
    )
    self.output_layer = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, n_features)

  def forward(self, x):
    x = x.repeat(self.seq_len, 1, 1)
    x = x.permute(1, 0, 2)
    x, (hidden_n, cell_n) = self.rnn1(x)
    x, (hidden_n, cell_n) = self.rnn2(x)
    return self.output_layer(x)

class RecurrentAutoencoder(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, seq_len, n_features, embedding_dim=64):
    super(RecurrentAutoencoder, self).__init__()

    self.encoder = Encoder(seq_len, n_features, embedding_dim).to(device)
    self.decoder = Decoder(seq_len, embedding_dim, n_features).to(device)

  def forward(self, x):
    print("Inputs size:", x.size())
    x = self.encoder(x)
    print("Representation size: ", x.size())
    x = self.decoder(x)
    print("Outputs size: ", x.size())
    return x

batch_n = 5
seq_len = 10
n_features = 3
inputs = torch.randn(batch_n, seq_len, n_features).to(device)

model = RecurrentAutoencoder(seq_len, n_features).to(device)
y = model(inputs)
```

Outputs:

```
Inputs size: torch.Size([5, 10, 3])
Representation size:  torch.Size([1, 5, 64])
Outputs size:  torch.Size([5, 10, 3])
```

Beware the representation (i.e outputs of encoder) have shape `(1, batch_size, embedding_dim)`

Comment: I appreciate the time you took in your answer, I am comparing our code together right now and seeing that I have some fundamental errors with my understanding of how this architecture works. Where did you learn this in such great detail? All of the sources I have looked up differ from yours, and led me to my worries, and ML books are very broad with how they explain autoencoders.

Comment: I learn concept of LSTM Autoencoder from this research paper call the: [Unsupervised Learning of Video Representations using LSTMs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.04681), and the implementation mainly from following two article; Keras: [A Gentle Introduction to LSTM Autoencoders](https://machinelearningmastery.com/lstm-autoencoders/), Pytorch: [Time Series Anomaly Detection using LSTM Autoencoders with PyTorch in Python](https://curiousily.com/posts/time-series-anomaly-detection-using-lstm-autoencoder-with-pytorch-in-python/)

Comment: Great, I've added those to my nightly reading list.

Comment: Always learn the high level abstract concept first before implementation, and the best place to learn those concept is in corresponding research paper where those concept is originally proposed, and I don't suggest you read those article through every words, what i did just go through the materials and pay attention on things I care the most (save great amount of time, I get info I need from those two article within 10 minutes), have good day : )